# Artifactory Helm repo cannot auto reindex. What could be wrong?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, artifactory

I have a Helm repo in Artifactory and once I upload a specific Helm chart, automatic reindexing stops working. If I manually reindex it works fine. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log after deploying a helm artifact? Kindly share those log snippets and steps used to reproduce the issue along with the Artifactory version.

Comment: @TataraoVana tried to reproduce and it seems that index becomes broken, when I copy whole bunch of helm packages as a folder between repos. Did not why it causes helm inxex corruption.